# How to access property specified in eclipse VM argument?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to access below property specified in eclipse VM argument:

-Ddata.life=dev

E.g. I have to get value **dev**

Answer (score 2):

You access VM properties in java program using System.getProperty.
SO, for your case you will do something like -

```
System.getProperty("data.life")
```

Comment: thanks, just got another answer, we can get the property value in spring by using following code snipet:               

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:${data.life}.properties</value> 
        </list>
        </property> 
    </bean>